# How to make Beamer slide to be automatically displayed

Tags: beamer, animations

I made a presentation using Beamer class of Tex Live. But it looks very ordinary. I want to bring into some animations such as slides should change automatically after few seconds. I tried doinf it with the command `\transduration{0.75}` as shown. However, it is not working.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my good goal.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is wonderful experience.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please suggest some alternatives.

Comment: Pretty please, don't call a presentation a "ppt". It's the name of the old PowerPoint format which is obsolete now.

Comment: Simply call it PDF, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The effect of`\transduration` is limited to the *Full Screen* / *Presentation* modes of *Evince*, *Adobe Reader* and possibly other PDF readers.

Comment: and often only possible with `acroread`

Comment: @Herbert: Other readers work too. Answer edited.

Comment: Ah good to know. Using `acroread' is no fun ...